# What do I need to change in my _form.html.erb or controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, controller

I have this in my listings controller:

```
   # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @options_for_select_ary = Subcategory.all.map{|subcategory| subcategory.subcategory_name}
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
    @options_for_select_ary = Subcategory.all.map{|subcategory| subcategory.subcategory_name}
  end
```

..and this in my _form.html.erb:

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subcategory %>
    <%= f.select :subcategory, options_for_select([@options_for_select_ary]) %>
  </div>
```

...it works, however, it only has one option available in the drop down.

Where or what do I need to change to make it display all of the subcategories?

Any help much appreciated...

Comment: `options_for_select(@options_for_select_ary)`

Comment: this worked, as below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to pass the values in Array. `map` always returns you an array.

Replace the following

```
<%= f.select :subcategory, options_for_select([@options_for_select_ary]) %>
```

with

```
<%= f.select :subcategory, options_for_select(@options_for_select_ary) %>
```

Also, you might want to change the below code

```
 # GET /listings/new
 def new
   @options_for_select_ary = Subcategory.pluck(:subcategory_name)
   @listing = Listing.new
 end

 # GET /listings/1/edit
 def edit
   @options_for_select_ary = Subcategory.pluck(:subcategory_name)
 end
```

Or better move it to an `before_action`

```
before_action :set_options, only: [:new, :edit]

# GET /listings/new
def new
  @listing = Listing.new
end

# GET /listings/1/edit
def edit
end

private

def set_options
  @options_for_select_ary = Subcategory.pluck(:subcategory_name)
end
```

**EDIT**

> undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

you might want to add `:update` and `:create` in `before_action`

```
before_action :set_options, only: [:new, :edit, :create, :update]
```

Comment: am now getting undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  tap
Extracted source (around line #29):
27
28
29
30
31
32
              
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :subcategory %>
    <%= f.select :subcategory, options_for_select(@options_for_select_ary) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/listings/new.html.erb

Comment: ahh. you might want to add `[:update, :create]` as well

Comment: because if there is an error in form it renders `new` or `edit` template from `create` or `update` action